# Obstacles and Background not scrolling at the same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Me and a friend from college have a game idea where obstacles are pooled in an object pool and then scrolled across the screen (from right to left) at the same speed the background scrolls (from right to left) to give the illusion the player's character is running. This works so far.

However, we want to make it so that the background and obstacles gradually increase in speed as time goes on while remaining the same speed as each other to make the game harder for the user.

We've had loads of trouble implementing this. Originally we tried to add a speed modifier to both base speeds but this resulted in wildly different speeds. I believe it has something to do with the fact we're using a texture offset to move the background but for obstacles we're using velocity. If it helps, everything (apart from the background, the camera, EventSystem and GameController) is within a canvas because that was the only way we knew how to scale at the time.

So, what are we doing wrong here?

Background Scrolling Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Background : MonoBehaviour
{

/*
 * 
 * A script that's sole purpose is to create a scrolling, infinite background.
 * Attached to: Brick
 * Scene: Level0
 *
 */

public float scrollSpeed;
private Vector2 savedOffset;
private Renderer rndrer;
private float conversionFactor = 0.1f;
public static Background instance;

private void Start()
{
    rndrer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    savedOffset = rndrer.material.GetTextureOffset("_MainTex");
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    this.rndrer.material.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2((GameControl.speed * conversionFactor), 0));
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    rndrer.sharedMaterial.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", savedOffset);
}
}
```

Obstacle Scrolling Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ObstacleScrolling : MonoBehaviour
{

/*
 * 
 * A script which controls the movement of the Obstacles to make it look like the player is running towards them.
 * Attached to: [All Obstacles in the Prefabs folder]
 * Scene: Level0
 * 
 */

private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
public float scrollSpeed;
public float test;
GameObject canvasObj;
Canvas canvas;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    canvasObj = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
    canvas = canvasObj.GetComponent<Canvas>();

    test = -1280 * canvas.scaleFactor;

    scrollSpeed = scrollSpeed * canvas.scaleFactor; //+ -(Time.timeSinceLevelLoad / 100);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    this.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * GameControl.speed);

    if (GameControl.instance.gameOver == true)
    {
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should include your code in your question, as external links can expire.

Comment: @Draco18s They're quite big though, but I'll do that now.

Comment: the reason that the background and the obstacles are not scrolling with the same speed is because you don't take units into account. offset is in pixels. distance is in meters. time is in seconds. velocity is in meters per second. the basic formula is: "delta distance = speed * delta time". in your code you use time (seconds) as offset (pixels) and you hope that it will match velocity (meters per second).

Comment: @JinJi That's what I thought. So, where do you suggest we go from here? We have made some adjustments, which I've edited in above.

Comment: @jamesfromit choose either pixels or "meters" (or whatever Unity's distance unit is) - but keep only one of them and convert the other. if you choose pixels, you have to convert obstacle translation to pixels (and keep background offset in pixels) - and if you choose "meters", convert background offset to meters (and keep obstacle translation in meters). for conversion factors see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501152/how-many-pixels-in-a-unit-in-unity3d

Comment: @JinJi So, we just divide by 100 on the obstacle scrolling?

Comment: use one global `float speed` (don't calculate it twice, store it in a singleton if you have to) and use `this.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed);` for obstacles and `this.rndrer.material.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(speed * conversionFactor, 0));` for background. `float conversionFactor` could depend on resolution.

Comment: @JinJi If we don't calculate, the speed variable twice how are we going to the game speed up as time progresses? Will we just add or multiply a speedModifier calculated elsewhere to the speeds?

Comment: make another script `SpeedCalculator : MonoBehaviour` and in its `Update` function calculate `speed += 0.01f * Time.deltaTime;` use an instance of `public SpeedCalculator speedCalculator` inside `Background` and inside `ObstacleScrolling` and assign it in editor.

Comment: @JinJi So, the speed will be calculated in a separate script? Sounds promising, we'll try it when we're next in Unity.

Comment: @JinJi It looks like our background is no longer moving but our obstacles are. Updated the code above to reflect what our C# scripts look like now. Are missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour
{
private static float speedFactor = 1.0f; // you can set this to canvas scale
private static float speed = 1.0f;

public static float ScaledSpeed
{
    get
    {
        return speed * speedFactor;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    speed += 0.01f * Time.deltaTime;
}
}
```

and this:

```
public class Background : MonoBehaviour
{
private Vector2 savedOffset;
private Vector2 offset;
private Renderer rndrer;
private float conversionFactor = 0.1f;

private void Start()
{
    rndrer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    savedOffset = rndrer.material.GetTextureOffset("_MainTex");
    offset = savedOffset;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    offset += new Vector2(GameControl.ScaledSpeed * conversionFactor, 0);
    this.rndrer.material.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", offset);
}
}
```

and this:

```
public class ObstacleScrolling : MonoBehaviour
{
void FixedUpdate()
{
    this.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * GameControl.ScaledSpeed);
}
}
```

Comment: So far, so good. We're having trouble adding canvas.scaleFactor thought to make the experience feel consistent across multiple resolutions. Do you have a suggestion on how we make this work?

Comment: i edited the answer. use `float ScaledSpeed` instead of `float speed`. adjust `float speedFactor` when resolution changes and you can also adjust the `float conversionFactor` if you have to.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. Answer accepted, enjoy the rep. :)